# find the number of times a character occurs between two indexes

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was given an input string, which is formed of N number of repetitions of a base string.
I need to find the occurrence of 'b' between two index points.

string mystr="ababba"
number of repetitions = 1000 ,
find occurrence of 'b' between two indexes, say 120 and 250.

I cannot use brute force where I increment my way upto 120 and then count the number of 'b' till the end index, this times out for large input string.

I have calculated and stored the occurrence of b in the the string of 6 character "ababba" as 3.
how do I proceed?

```
for( auto& each : mystr)
{
    if (each == 'b')
        cntb++;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [scheduling an appointment with your rubber duck to review your planned solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: Don't knock it until you have tried it `:)` The duck would probably talk about the number of times the full string occurs between `120-250` (you already know how many `'b'`s are in your string), and then he would probably suggest checking the ending substring between `120` and the start of the first full string, and the beginning substring left-over after the last full string before `250`. The the final quack would be about adding the no. of `'b'` from the ending and beginning substrings with product of the number of full strings times the number of `'b'`s in the full string.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char inputString[11];
    int b_in_string, b_occurrence, repetitions, startIndex, endIndex, actual_needed_count;

    cout<<"Input string: ";
    cin>>inputString;
    cout<<"Repetitions: ";
    cin>>repetitions;
    cout<<"Start index: ";
    cin>>startIndex;
    cout<<"End index: ";
    cin>>endIndex;

    if(endIndex < startIndex)
    {
        cout<<"End index must be larger than start index. Program terminated.";
        return 1;
    }

    b_in_string = 0;
    b_occurrence = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(inputString); i++)
    {
        if(inputString[i] == 'b')
        {
            b_in_string++;
        }
    }

    actual_needed_count = endIndex - startIndex + 1; //start and end indexes inclusive

    b_occurrence = b_in_string * actual_needed_count;

    cout<<"Number of times 'b' occurs: ";
    cout<<b_occurrence;

    return 0;
}
```

It works on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler. Hope it helps.